# Play audio from remote Url in Ionic(Hybrid app Development using cordova)

Tags: web-services, cordova, audio, ionic-framework

I am new to both Ionic and Cordova. I'm creating a basic app where I'll have some  URLs of audio files that I want users to be able to play.
     These URLs are fetching from web service. Please help me with this query. Thanks.

Edited after trying your answer:

following is the web service response. There is multiple event.Each event has  two different audio that I want to play in one section.

{
"message":"success",
"title":"Panchkavani",
"error_msg":"",
"result":[
{"events_id":null,
"image":"",
"title":"test pachkavani",
"stanak":"https://ionic-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/Message%20in%20a%20bottle.mp3",
"mandir":"https://ionic-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/Roxane.mp3","date_added":"Saturday, 13-May-2017","date_time":"01:49 AM"}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a sample . *dont forget to install* **cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media** for more https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/11/playing-audio-android-ios-ionicframework-app/.this sample slso works only if you add media plugin

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ionic-audio'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
 
  $scope.tracks = [
        {
            url: 'https://ionic-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/Message%20in%20a%20bottle.mp3',
            artist: 'The Police',
            title: 'Message in a bottle',
            art: 'https://ionic-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/The_Police_Greatest_Hits.jpg'
        },
        {
            url: 'https://ionic-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/Roxane.mp3',
            artist: 'The Police',
            title: 'Roxane',
            art: 'https://ionic-audio.s3.amazonaws.com/The_Police_Greatest_Hits.jpg'
        }
    ];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Ionic Pull to Refresh</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/arielfaur/ionic-audio/master/dist/ion-audio.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Audio tracks with embedded bar</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content>
    <div class="list">
      <ion-audio-track ng-repeat="track in tracks" track="track">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="item item-thumbnail-left">
            <img src="{{track.art}}">

            <h2>{{track.title}}</h2>

            <p>{{track.artist}}</p>
            <ion-audio-controls>
              <a class="button button-icon icon" ion-audio-play></a>
              <ion-spinner icon="ios" style="position: relative; top: 8px; left: 4px"></ion-spinner>
            </ion-audio-controls>
          </div>
          <div class="item item-divider">
            <ion-audio-progress-bar display-time></ion-audio-progress-bar>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ion-audio-track>
    </div>
  </ion-content>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution. But audio files are not playing. It keep showing loading imgage infinitely. What went wrong?

Comment: did you install `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media`

Comment: Yes. I am using Visual studio that's why i installed this plugins in visual studio.

Comment: There was issue with media plugin. I solved that and now audio files are playing properly. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this code. But i want ask one question the how audio is playing even though URL is not provided in the html page design?

Comment: Is there any inbuilt functionality of <ion-audio-track> tag? Please help me out. I want play two audio in every track. following is the my web service response there is two url that I want to play.